# Using .lib file in linux

Tags: linux, web-services, .lib

I have been given a dukpt.lib file and corresponding header file.
I have to make a webservice in c++ (gSOAP)which internally make use of methods from  dukpt.lib

dukpt.lib make use of win api internally . so my question is :Is there any possible way to make my webservice on linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. There's a faint chance you might be able to use it somehow via WINE, but if that isn't immediately apparent to you, you are very unlikely to be able to get it to work.

Comment: thanku for response ..can you please suggest me a good link where I can learn how to use wine regarding this...I am not familiar with linux at all

Comment: If you are not familiar with Linux at all, you do not have the necessary skills to pursue this task.

Comment: so i guess You mean that I have to make a .exe of webservice in windows environment  and deploy it in linux with help of wine..does it work this way..??

Comment: dukpt.lib make use of setupapi.lib from windows

Comment: Applications which make use of the Windows Setup API are not likely to port cleanly under WINE. There is probably a much better way of accomplishing what you are after, but your question is too narrow to give you a more useful answer.